# hang up codes for free switch in Lua

Tags: lua, freeswitch

```lua
session:answer()

if ( session:answer() == 1) then

        freeswitch.consoleLog('info', '\n................... callanswered ..............\n')

else

        freeswitch.consoleLog('info', '\n................... call not answered ..............\n')

end
--freeswitch.consoleLog('info', '\n...................'.. session:hangup()  ..'..............\n')

session:hangup()
```

but it is working only for call answered alone not for call not answered

Comment: So are you saying `session:answer()` always is always `1`?

Comment: Looking at the documentation are you sure you want `session:answer() == 1` and not `session:ready() == true`?

Comment: yes I just tried to use  freeswitch.consoleLog to print session:answer() it gave value like 1 but I didn't  any value for hang up ready() I didn't make use of it.